# DocumentDB (via MongoDB protocol) collection size limit in azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Without partitioning there is 10GB limit on each collection in Azure in MongoDB(Used the drivers on top of DocumentDB) and I have a collection whose size is 50GB.

Currently I have divided data on basis of a field and stored them in 6 different collections.

Should I be doing the partitioning (Don't know how to do it) or there is a way to increase this size limit?

Comment: Is this limit is bound to Azure only? Because mongodb does not limit to size of collection until the max size an instance can hold is reached.  However, there are some limitations on collection size for sharded env ~TBs of data.

Comment: Yes, this is bound to Azure only. After partitioning we can have 250GBs in one collection and this is not exactly mongodb - It is DocumentDB on top of that Azure creates one more layer to convert the mongo queries to document db queries.

Comment: This question may be misleading to some: You're talking about DocumentDB, not MongoDB. Everything regarding collections and pricing is specific to DocumentDB. MongoDB support is at the protocol/API level. I edited your title accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

DocumentDB collection management really has nothing to do with MongoDB access protocol. Collections are either non-partitioned (10GB cap) or partitioned (250GB and beyond).

How you divide your data between collections is up to you. But keep these things in mind when deciding between multiple non-partitioned collections and a single partitioned collection:

- The collection serves as a partition boundary, which includes stored procedures. If you need to work with content across collections, this could be an issue with your app, depending on its logic.
- Non-partitioned collections have Request Unit (RU) scale from 400-10,000. Partitioned collections start at <strike>10,100</strike> 2,500 RU. Depending on your app budget, this could impact your collection decision.
- You cannot convert a collection from non-partitioned <--> partitioned. If you decide to change the collection type, you'll need to create a new collection and move data between collections.

Comment: From customer support I found that partitioning is not possible if we use MongoDB protocols.

Comment: DocumentDB will be releasing a support for sharding soon. Please reach out to askdocdb {at} microsoft {dot} com if you'd like to be included in the preview.

Comment: Thanks David Makogon and Andrew Liu. For now I am using the old procedure where I have kept separated data by a field in different collection. But will be waiting for the sharding support.

Comment: @AndrewLiu, is the sharding support simply support for MongoDB's sharding API but will use DocumentDB's partitioned collections?